# DPDK is it possible to remove a rte_mbuff from a rte_mbuff array?

Tags: dpdk

i want to remove arp pakcet in r and send another packets normally.
here is my code

```
for (;;) {
    /*
     * Receive packets on a port and forward them on the paired
     * port. The mapping is 0 -> 1, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2, etc.
     */
    RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(port) {
        /* Get burst of RX packets, from first port of pair. */
        struct rte_mbuf *bufs[BURST_SIZE];
        uint16_t nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(port, 0,
                bufs, BURST_SIZE);
        if (unlikely(nb_rx == 0))
            continue;
        /* Send burst of TX packets, to second port of pair. */
    int delete_packet_num = 0;
    for(int i=0;i<nb_rx;i++){
        struct rte_mbuf *p = bufs[i];
        unsigned char *payload =(unsigned char*)p->buf_addr;
        payload = payload+p->data_off;
        struct ethhdr* eth_hdr = (struct ethhdr *)payload;
        if(eth_hdr->h_proto == 1544)
        {
            printf("there is a arp packet!\n");
            //remove a target mbuf or not?
            rte_pktmbuf_free(bufs[i]);
            delete_packet_num++;        
        }
    
    }
    nb_rx -=delete_packet_num;
    const uint16_t nb_tx = rte_eth_tx_burst(port ^ 1, 0,bufs, nb_rx);    
    if (unlikely(nb_tx < nb_rx)) {
        uint16_t buf;
        for (buf = nb_tx; buf < nb_rx; buf++)
            rte_pktmbuf_free(bufs[buf]);
    }
}
```

it can deny arp packets in my vmware machine.but the vm machine become very slow when the code run about half-hour minutes. i guess the:

```
rte_pktmbuf_free(bufs[i])
```

the code dont free the memory.
anyone can help me?

Comment: please update the following details 1) DPDK version 2) Is it PCIe pass through or virtual NIC? 3) Guest OS version 4) KVM-QEMU or XEN or virtual box 5) are the VCPU pinned? 6) is the guest memory delivered from Huge pages on host 7) amount host and guest os memory 8) swap disk is disabled on both guest and host. Also there is bug in the code where ARP packets removed is not replaced with valid next mbuf (please fix the code).

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments there is incorrect memory usage after freeing ARP packets. Hence the correct code to be used is

```
for (;;) {
    /*
     * Receive packets on a port and forward them on the paired
     * port. The mapping is 0 -> 1, 1 -> 0, 2 -> 3, 3 -> 2, etc.
     */
    RTE_ETH_FOREACH_DEV(port) {
        /* Get burst of RX packets, from first port of pair. */
        struct rte_mbuf *bufs[BURST_SIZE];
        uint16_t nb_rx = rte_eth_rx_burst(port, 0, bufs, BURST_SIZE);
        
        if (unlikely(nb_rx == 0))
            continue;

        /* Send burst of TX packets, to second port of pair. */
        int delete_packet_num = 0;
        int i = 0, j = 0;
        
        for(;i<nb_rx;i++){
            struct rte_mbuf *p = bufs[i];
            
            unsigned char *payload =(unsigned char*)p->buf_addr;
            payload = payload+p->data_off;
            struct ethhdr* eth_hdr = (struct ethhdr *)payload;
            
            if(eth_hdr->h_proto == 1544)
            {
                printf("there is a arp packet!\n");
                //remove a target mbuf or not?
                rte_pktmbuf_free(bufs[i]);
                delete_packet_num++;        
            }
            else
            {
                /*
                 for all valid packets update the list 
                 example:
                    - let nb_rx be 16 packets
                    - in which packet at index 5 is ARP packets
                    - with help of check for ARP we are reassigning bufs[5] = bufs[6], because j is running 1 step once it encounters ARP at index 5
                 */
                bufs[j++] = bufs[i];
            }
        }
    
    nb_rx -=delete_packet_num;
    const uint16_t nb_tx = rte_eth_tx_burst(port ^ 1, 0,bufs, nb_rx);    
    if (unlikely(nb_tx < nb_rx)) {
        uint16_t buf;
        for (buf = nb_tx; buf < nb_rx; buf++)
            rte_pktmbuf_free(bufs[buf]);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot,i have a different method to solve my problem.i read the rte_pktmbuf_free API and i notice the rte_pktmbuf_free can process NULL point,so i dont change the nb_rx value anymore and use rte_pktmbuf_free normally.lastly i free all nb_tx packet bufs.the code seem to run normally!

Comment: there is definitely wrong in freeing all successful `nb_tx` as it is freed up by the PMD. This is not the right way.